# MySQL spatial point

Tags: mysql, spatial, point

I have problem with ***spatial 'POINT'*** in mysql.

**Reproduce steps:**

Create new table (position) with column (geo - as point).

**Run this script:**

Insert into position (geo) values (Point(42.092192, 9.104411));

**Result:**

POINT(42.092192 9.104411000000001)

Comment: For my isn't acceptable because logically it is different position. Do you know what can be root of problem? Or how to fix it?

Comment: "For my isn't acceptable because logically it is different position" yea a different position of what like one `nanometer` (size off five atoms) ?.. Do you really need that kind of accuracy when doing geo positions?

Comment: @RaymondNijland i'm sorry but yes. The whole client database contains latitude, longtitude, and point positions... we are inserting data to multiple tables and test are doing cross check. So yes it is important for us to have very specific data and correct.

Comment: What means lon?

Comment: I edited the text.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Besides `Point` datatype is working with double precision what always has some kind of [floating point precision error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)